# How to change default buffer when opening new frame

Tags: buffers, frames

When I create a new frame with `make-frame-command`, it automatically opens the currently open buffer in the new frame. Is it possible to change this to open the scratch buffer instead? I'm using perspective.el.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a function that switches to the desired buffer, to the hook `after-make-frame-functions`:

```el
(defun my/switch-to-scratch (frame)
  (switch-to-buffer "*scratch*"))

(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'my/switch-to-scratch t)
```

Do `C-h v after-make-frame-functions` for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the trick. I had to add `(select-frame frame)` before modifying the buffer with `(dired "~")`. Otherwise, `dired` was performed in the old frame.